# Solve second degree polynomial by "completing the square"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I can find the first $x$, but not the other. I know that the other $x$ is equal to $-4$.

$$\begin{align*}
1 &= (x^2+2x+1)-8\\
9&=(x^2+2x+1)\\
9&= (x_1+1)^2\\
3&= x_1+1\\
2&= x_1
\end{align*}$$

How do I deduce what the other $x$ is by using the method "completing the square"?

Comment: The inverse of squaring is $\pm$ square root. You forgot to include the negative version when you undid the square.

Comment: You need to remember that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$. So the fourth line shuld read $3=|x+1|$, which means that *either* you have $3=x+1$, **or** you have $-3=x+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caution:

$$(x+1)^2=9\implies x+1=\color{red}{\pm 3}\implies\begin{cases}x_1+1=-3\implies x_1=-4\\{}\\x_2+1=3\implies x_2=2\end{cases}$$